# Construct a dictionary merging multiple lists

Tags: python, list

I have a list of objects (clusters) and each object has an attribute `vertices` which is a list of numbers. I want to construct a dictionary (using a one liner) such that the key is a vertex number and the value is the index of the corresponding cluster in the actual list.

Ex:

```
clusters[0].vertices = [1,2]
clusters[1].vertices = [3,4]
```

Expected Output:

```
{1:0,2:0,3:1,4:1}
```

I came up with the following:

```
dict(reduce(lambda x,y:x.extend(y) or x, [
     dict(zip(vertices, [index]*len(vertices))).items()
     for index,vertices in enumerate([i.vertices for i in clusters])]))
```

It works... but is there a better way of doing this?

Also comment on the efficiency of the above piece of code.

PS: The vertex lists are disjoint.

Comment: Did you mean Expected Output: {1:0, 2:0, 3:1, **4:1** } ?

Comment: I'd suggest that you write a function to do it and then your one-liner is a function call. [Readability counts](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly simple solution, using a nested `for`:

```
dict((vert, i) for (i, cl) in enumerate(clusters) for vert in cl.vertices)
```

This is also more efficient than the version in the question, since it doesn't build lots of intermediate lists while collecting the data for the dict.